# using route Provider in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, ngroute

I'm having a problem using route provider.
I am calling a different path in my localhost:8080/showThemes.html page using a like this way:

```
<a ng-href="#/category/{{themes.theme}}">
  <img class="imgCenter" ng-src="{{themes.image}}">
</a>
```

and in my controller I wrote:

```
var showThemes = angular.module('showThemes',['ngCookies','ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     // configure the routing rules here
     $routeProvider.when('/category/frozen/', {
       templateUrl: '../frozen.html',
       controller: 'showFrozenController',
     });
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
     });
})
```

I don't have any errors in my console but it doesn't redirect to frozen.html page.

How can I solve this?

Comment: check browser dev tools network to see what happens to template request. Not good idea to use `../` in path. Also mixing hash and html5mode

Answer (score 0):

When you have HTML5 mode enable you shouldn't have # for routing. So can you check:

```
<a ng-href="/category/{{themes.theme}}">
```